# _MissingDynamic: `license` defined outside of `pyproject.toml` is ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

For the last 24 hours or so I'm seeing the below error messages when I try to install either of sexpdata 1.0.1 or segno 1.5.3 in python.

I should perhaps note that these installs usually happen via github code runners (automated tests), which is what alerted me to the issue.  I can reproduce locally.

My requirements.txt hasn't changed in many weeks and no substantive changes for even longer.  Climbing back up the commit tree doesn't change the error.  So I suspect the problem isn't in my code, but I also am not sure where the problem might lie, as sexpdata hasn't changed since June, according to its [github repo](https://github.com/jd-boyd/sexpdata).

Any pointers what might be happening or what to look at?

```
Collecting sexpdata>=0.0.3 (from epc)
  Using cached sexpdata-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.6 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:75: _MissingDynamic: `license` defined outside of `pyproject.toml` is ignored.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The following seems to be defined outside of `pyproject.toml`:
      
              `license = 'BSD License'`
      
              According to the spec (see the link below), however, setuptools CANNOT
              consider this value unless `license` is listed as `dynamic`.
      
              https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/
      
              To prevent this problem, you can list `license` under `dynamic` or alternatively
              remove the `[project]` table from your file and rely entirely on other means of
              configuration.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        _handle_missing_dynamic(dist, project_table)
      /tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:75: _MissingDynamic: `keywords` defined outside of `pyproject.toml` is ignored.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The following seems to be defined outside of `pyproject.toml`:
      
              `keywords = ['s-expression', 'lisp', 'parser']`
      
              According to the spec (see the link below), however, setuptools CANNOT
              consider this value unless `keywords` is listed as `dynamic`.
      
              https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/
      
              To prevent this problem, you can list `keywords` under `dynamic` or alternatively
              remove the `[project]` table from your file and rely entirely on other means of
              configuration.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        _handle_missing_dynamic(dist, project_table)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/www/danube/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/www/danube/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/var/www/danube/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 159, in setup
          dist.parse_config_files()
        File "/var/www/danube/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_virtualenv.py", line 21, in parse_config_files
          result = old_parse_config_files(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 627, in parse_config_files
          pyprojecttoml.apply_configuration(self, filename, ignore_option_errors)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py", line 67, in apply_configuration
          return _apply(dist, config, filepath)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py", line 56, in apply
          _apply_project_table(dist, config, root_dir)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py", line 82, in _apply_project_table
          corresp(dist, value, root_dir)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ga37r2a6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py", line 183, in _license
          _set_config(dist, "license", val["text"])
      KeyError: 'text'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Have you upgraded `pip` and/or `setuptools` recently?

Comment: After this began, yes.  It didn't help.  Before this started, I'm not aware of having down so (and requirements.txt doesn't specify versions, so git is unaware of the version history of those two).

Comment: pip is currently 23.3.1, setuptools 69.0.1

Comment: Hmm, downgrading sexpdata==1.0.0 makes the symptom go away, but that has not been what my requirements.txt has called for, at least since June.  Something else must have changed since outside what I specify, but not sure what.

Comment: Note that pip freeze doesn't include all that pip list does, so things like pip and setuptools versions _migth_ have changed without my knowing it.

Answer (score 7):

This was caused by the release of `setuptools 69.0.0` on Nov 20, 2023, which has a list of [deprecations and removals](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#deprecations-and-removals). The setup files (e.g. `pyproject.toml`) of `sexpdata 1.0.1` or `segno 1.5.3` must have some things that do not comply with the latest rules. A simple fix is to change `requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]` to `requires = ["setuptools==68.2.2"]` in the `pyproject.toml` file of `sexpdata 1.0.1`, then the package should be able to be installed again. A permanent fix should update the setup files to make them comply with the rules.

Answer (score -1):

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools == 68.2.2"]
```